# application for copying and reading pdf and word documents in ipad

Tags: ipad

I am looking for an application similar to iBooks which I can use to copy general PDF and Word Documents from Itunes offline and read them. I already have dropbox but the issue with it is it requires connection to internet from IPad to download the documents. I need something similar to IBooks that would work for these formats. I already use IBooks to read my ebooks in pdf format and it works great. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Secondly, is there a way to create folders within IBooks such as Books and Papers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mobile File Access tools like
[FileSpirit](http://www.file-spirit.com)
to download and read the PDF and Word documents to the iPad.